# Latest version of PSWebServiceLibrary

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm currently playing with the prestashop webservice but there is a version issue between the PSWebServiceLibrary.php used in documention (1.6) and the last version of prestashop.

Does someone know which changes I have to do in the lib or where can I find the updated library ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to edit the PSWebserviceLibrary.php. Then the library works fine.

Change:

```
const psCompatibleVersionsMin = '1.4.0.0';
const psCompatibleVersionsMax = '1.6.99.99';
```

To:

```
const psCompatibleVersionsMin = '1.4.0.0';
const psCompatibleVersionsMax = '1.7.99.99';
```

just let me know if it works.